# Make CKEditor4 ignore Google AdSense code

Tags: iframe, ckeditor, adsense

I'm using CKEditor4 to edit my page content inline. However, when I add a Google AdSense code to the raw HTML of my content and load up the inline editor, the script gets executed and a new `iframe` is placed within my editable `div`. When I save the page, it will save both the iframe and the script; so the next time I fire up the inline editor it will create another.

This is getting really annoying and I was wondering if anyone knows how to prevent CKEditor4 from executing the `<script>` tag in the editor itself.

I've been googling all day for a solution, but can't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter any kind of code both when it's parsed and returned. The easiest way, I guess, is removing the `iframe` when editor data is being saved. Frankly, I'm not really into AdSense but I observed that generated code is an `ins` tag wrapped in paragraph. You can eventually extend this filter to be more specific, if you want.

```
CKEDITOR.inline( 'editable', {
    on: {
        instanceReady: function() {
            this.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
                elements: {
                    p: function( element ) {
                        var children = element.children;
                        for ( var i = children.length; i--; ) {
                            if ( children[ i ].name == 'ins' )
                                return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } );
        }
    }
} );
```

Also read about [`dataProcessor`](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Data_Processor) it's a powerful tool in CKEditor. You'll do magic once you got it.

Comment: Your mention of the `ins` tag made me think of an even simpler approach. Before submitting my data I just `$("ins").remove();`